# How to get data from other table in laravel using id?

Tags: database, laravel

i want to display the user's name in the post who post the project. but its showing ERROR : Trying to get property of non-object in view file.

i have user table and project table. in project table i have foreign key user_id. but i couldn't access the name of the user and even the user id from the user table. in project table the user_id is 0 and it is not same as in user table. how i should solve this?

user model:

```
 public function project()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}
```

project model:

```
public function User() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

migration users table:

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
```

Migration project table:

```
   Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->timestamps('date');


    });
```

view file:

```
   @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
   <tr>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
    <td> {{$project->user_id->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $project->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $project->date }}</td>
```

Comment: The users table `id` must correspond to the `user_id` in projects table. This is where the relationship exists. Have you inspected this to be correct?

Comment: the id in the user table and the user_id in project table is not same. in project table all the id is 0. how i should correct this?

Comment: How do you create the project in the first place, can you show a snippet from your controller or wherever you add new record to project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) correct small mistake form your table such as user_id and User_id

2) Let me solve first relationships:

One user can have many project.
one project can belongs to one user.

Model class solve

```
class Project extend Modeletcc
{
    public function projectusers() {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Project', 'user_id', 'id);
    }

}
```

then get data from controller such as

```
class ProjectController extends Controller {

      // to get data
      public function __contstruct() {
          $this->project = Project::with('projectusers')->get();
      }

    // function for ending data to view 
    public function tesview() {

    return view('view whic you wanna send your data', 
         [
           'project_details' => $this->project
         ]);
    }
```

then inside view you can simple get all data which you want

## view  blade u can simple get them with normal php

```
@foreach($project_details as $project) {

           @foreach($project->projectusers as $users) {
              {{ $user->name }} 
            }

   }
```

Comment: why its showing error :Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ?

Comment: ok get it with print_r() then solve it.  <?php print_r($project) ?> see what is inside of it then u can solve it easy

Answer (score 0):

You cant access user who posted the project through the project id. You need to reference the relationship and then call the model property. Like so:

```
  @foreach ($projects as   $project)
   <tr>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
    <td> {{$project->user->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $project->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $project->date }}</td>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: write the method name in lowercase user